# Mouse click doesn't fire event with Crafty.js

Tags: javascript, mouseclick-event, craftyjs

I've been trying to build a game using Crafty.js. I have an image that serves as a button, and once the user clicks on it he will be led to the next page. However, for some reason the mouse click just isn't firing. Any ideas?

```
Crafty.scene('Main', function () {
  Crafty.background("url('images/homeBackground.jpg')");
  Crafty.e('2D, DOM, Mouse, next').attr({ //next is the image
    x: 600,
    y: 600,
    w: 100,
    h: 50
  }).bind('click', function (e) {
    alert("Here?"); //this isn't firing
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Event names are case sensitive, you should bind to the `Click` event.

More details at: http://craftyjs.com/api/Mouse.html